# (Microsoft Access) How to Input multiple new records with 2 out of 5 fields from being reset

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-forms

I am trying to create an input form to input new entry into my table.
Basically, I have a simple table with 5 field. DATE, PERSON, Value x, Value y, Value z.

Every time I finished input a new record, the form reset to blank. I really need the Date and Person Field to keep the previous record value so I dont have to input them again and again. Only reset Value X,Y,Z.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

For the date field, use the *AfterUpdate* event of the form to set the *DefaultValue* property as a text expression of the date value:

```vb
Me![Date].DefaultValue = "#" & Format(Me![Date].Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#"
```

Similar for the other fields.